A childrens TV show about the Prime Ministers son
I've a vague memory of a childrens TV show which was around in my youth (probably late 1990's, early 2000's) which involved a school-aged child of the British Prime Minister.
I seem to remember that the child's perspective always saved the PMs political bacon.
I'm asking because I'm trying to track down an episode of it which involved the political slogan "putting everything first", which promises everything while meaning nothing (sound familiar?).
Anyone got a clue what this show was?

Correct @Paulie_D

Likely: My Dad's The Prime Minister (2003 - 2004)

Wikipedia:

My Dad's the Prime Minister is a British sitcom written by Ian Hislop and Nick Newman. It centres on the life of the Prime Minister, his family and his spin doctor. Its main cast include Robert Bathurst, Joe Prospero, Carla Mendonça, Brian Bovell and Emma Sackville.
Series 1 was shown on BBC 1 as part of CBBC, in April and May 2003. Season 2 was shown later in the evening on BBC 1, in November and December 2004. Series 1 focused more on Dillon (the Prime Minister's son), while the second season had greater coverage of the life of the Prime Minister. Series 1 was released on DVD and video, but currently Series 2 remains unreleased.

